# What is the formula to calculate the percentage loss without touching the original value?

Tags: percentages

I have $2000$ dollars, and I lost $20$% of it in the first month of investment.

In the second month, I got $20$% increase on the value I had left from the loss of the past month.

So, I had $2000$ dollars at first and lost $20$%. So I had $1600$ dollars left.

In the next month, those $1600$ dollars had a $20$% return and then I have $1920$ dollars.

I lost $4$% of my original investment in two months.

Having only the percentage gain and increase, how do you find the $4$% without making calculations with the original value?

Say I have $20$% loss in the first month, then $20$% gain of the remaining value. How do I use those two percentages to find that $4$%?

Comment: $1.2\times.8=.96$

Comment: 100% - 20% = 80%; 80% + 20% of 80% = 96% = 100% - 4%

Comment: Sorry for formating the values as code, I'm coming from StackOverflow XD

Answer (score 0):

We have
\begin{align}
x_0 &= 2000 \\
x_1 &= x_0 (1 - p_1) \quad p_1 = 20\% = 20 / 100 = 0.2 \\
x_2 &= x_1 (1 + p_2) \quad p_2 = p_1 \\
\end{align}
where $x_i$ is the money amount after $i$ months passed.

We can combine the last two equations into
$$
x_2 = x_0 (1 - p_1)(1+ p_1)  = x_0 (1 - p_1^2) = x_0 (1-0.04)
$$
which means a decrease of $4\%$ from $x_0$ to $x_2$.